# Perimeter function in geosphere package

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, spatial, geosphere

I want to give a set of coordinates to the function perimeter function in geosphere package in R and the coordinates do not form a closed polygon. Will the function give me length of the line segments or close the polygon itself and give the perimeter ?

The data is as follows:

```
     lon      lat
78.53346 17.36927
78.53476 17.36833
78.53018 17.36844
78.52730 17.36850
78.52597 17.36853
78.52527 17.36854
78.52189 17.36862
78.51889 17.36885
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not need a closed polygon.  If you give it a closed polygon, it will remove the last line.  You can use `getMethod("perimeter","matrix")` to view the source.

```
if (isTRUE(all.equal(x[1, ], x[nrow(x), ]))) {
  x <- x[-nrow(x), ]
```

This is checking if the last row is equal to the first row.  In that case it removes the last row.

```
myPoly<-matrix(c(78.53346,78.53476,78.53018,78.52730,78.52597,78.52527,78.52189,78.51889,
             17.36927,17.36927,17.36844,17.36850,17.36853,17.36854,17.36862,17.36885),
             nrow=8,ncol=2)

perimeter(myPoly)
```

Results:

```
[1] 3382.831
```

To find the length between two points, you can use the `distHaversine()` directly.

```
distHaversine(myPoly[1,],myPoly[8,],r = 6378137)
```

Result:

```
1548.674
```

The length without the last line could be found by taking the difference.

```
perimeter(myPoly) - distHaversine(myPoly[1,],myPoly[8,],r = 6378137)
[1] 1834.157
```

or

```
sum(distHaversine(myPoly[c(1:nrow(myPoly)-1),],myPoly[-1,]))
[1] 1834.157
```

Comment: So it follows the path and finds the length of curve ? I need the length of path traced and not a closed polygon. Thanks.